# changing product layout, need to display 3 column in zencart

Tags: zen-cart

I want to display similar like [Please click to look example](http://www.jaysonhome.com/furniture/sofas.html) in zen-cart website..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following plugin.

http://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=3

Make sure to back up your db and follow the instructions on how to install.  Then you can set it to 3 columns and have it display as you want.